# Python MYSQL Data Inserted Twice

Tags: python, mysql

When a single hash is found in the tweet URL , The script inserts the values into `MYSQL` DB properly . When there is 2 or more hash found in the tweet URL , The records are `inserted` twice in the MYSQL DB.

For example , If a tweet has 2 URLS with hashes mentioned , In MYSQL DB 4 records are created.

DB State:

```
"https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/2819e520dea611c4dd1c3b1fd54adbd0c50963ff75d67cc7facbe2090574afc0/analysis/","2017-09-20 01:00:35","2819e520dea611c4dd1c3b1fd54adbd0c50963ff75d67cc7facbe2090574afc0"
"https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/8084880e875b4dc97ccd9f97249d4c7184f6be092679d2b272ece2890306ca89/analysis/","2017-09-20 01:03:35","8084880e875b4dc97ccd9f97249d4c7184f6be092679d2b272ece2890306ca89"
"https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/b5034183d4d2aca1e586b4a4bf22f32e4204c4b6d288c171d5252636c11248a0/analysis/","2017-09-20 01:03:35","8084880e875b4dc97ccd9f97249d4c7184f6be092679d2b272ece2890306ca89"
"https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/8084880e875b4dc97ccd9f97249d4c7184f6be092679d2b272ece2890306ca89/analysis/","2017-09-20 01:03:35","b5034183d4d2aca1e586b4a4bf22f32e4204c4b6d288c171d5252636c11248a0"
"https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/b5034183d4d2aca1e586b4a4bf22f32e4204c4b6d288c171d5252636c11248a0/analysis/","2017-09-20 01:03:35","b5034183d4d2aca1e586b4a4bf22f32e4204c4b6d288c171d5252636c11248a0"
```

Any suggestions on how to insert only single entries to DB ?

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from __future__ import print_function
import tweepy
import json
import MySQLdb
import time
import json, urllib, urllib2, argparse, hashlib, re, sys
from dateutil import parser

WORDS = ['virustotal']

CONSUMER_KEY = "XXXX"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "YYY"
ACCESS_TOKEN = "AAAA"
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "DDDDD"


HOST = "192.168.150.1"
USER = "admin"
PASSWD = "admin"
DATABASE = "twitter"


def store_data(values, insert_time, insert_hash):
    db=MySQLdb.connect(host=HOST, user=USER, passwd=PASSWD, db=DATABASE, charset="utf8")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    data = []
    #print(hashes)
    for value in values:
         data.append((value, insert_time, insert_hash))
    cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO tweet_url VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""",data)
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
    return

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_connect(self):
        print("We are now connected to the streaming API.")

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print('An Error has occured: ' + repr(status_code))
        return False

    def on_data(self, data):
      try:
        datajson = json.loads(data)
        web_url= datajson['entities']['urls']
        #print(web_url)
        urls=[]
        for i in web_url:
            urls.append((i['expanded_url']))
        values = [list([item]) for item in urls]
        list_url = ','.join([str(i) for i in values])
        extract_url=str(list_url)
        formatted_url=''.join(extract_url)
        sha256_hash=re.findall(r"([a-fA-F\d]{64})", formatted_url)
        hashes=''.join(sha256_hash)
        insert_time=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        hash_list=re.findall(r"([a-fA-F\d]{64})", hashes)
        for insert_hash in hash_list:
             store_data(values, insert_time, insert_hash)
        print(store_data)
        print(hashes)
        print(type(hashes))
      except Exception as e:
             print(e)



auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
listener = StreamListener(api=tweepy.API(wait_on_rate_limit=True))
streamer = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth, listener=listener)
print("Tracking: " + str(WORDS))
streamer.filter(track=WORDS)
```

Comment: My Python skills are somewhat lacking compared to my SQL, but it looks like there's a missing `JOIN` or something. In your example data, the URL and the hashes are cross joining (for example, your URL and hashes look something like `[abc,abc],[abc,def],[def,abc],[def,def]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a first loop :

```
for insert_hash in hash_list:
    store_data(values, insert_time, insert_hash)
```

And then you loop again on the values to build the data list of tuples :

```
for value in values:
    data.append((value, insert_time, insert_hash))
```

So the values are called twice.

---

Maybe you could use `zip()` or `enumerate()` to join the `hash_list` and the `values` before calling `store_data` ?

```
data = []
if len(values) == len(hash_list):
    for val,hash in zip(values, hash_list):
        data.append((val, insert_time, hash))
    store_data(data)
```

And then, no need to loop again inside `store_data()`, just change the signature to pass directly the data list:

```
def store_data(data_list):
    # connection to database
    cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO tweet_url VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""",data_list)
```

Comment: Moureu : Used the method mentioned above. It works perfect. Thank you

Comment: @Arun thanks ;). small hint with this kind of issue with loops, add some `print`  (or any logger) inside before calling your function, it helps to understand what values are given as parameters